# Constantly getting this error in arcade when running my game

Tags: python, arcade

I am getting this error when trying to run my code, the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Colin Lewis/pythonProject3/Lib/import_tileset.py", line 264, in <module>
    main()

  File "D:/Colin Lewis/pythonProject3/Lib/import_tileset.py", line 259, in main
    window.setup()

  File "D:/Colin Lewis/pythonProject3/Lib/import_tileset.py", line 181, in setup
    self.scene.add_sprite(LAYER_NAME_PLAYER, self.player_sprite)

  File "D:\Colin Lewis\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\arcade\scene.py", line 95, in add_sprite
    new_list.append(sprite)

  File "D:\Colin Lewis\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\arcade\sprite_list\sprite_list.py", line 625, in append
    self._atlas.add(texture)

  File "D:\Colin Lewis\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\arcade\texture_atlas.py", line 284, in add
    if self.has_texture(texture):

  File "D:\Colin Lewis\pythonProject3\lib\site-packages\arcade\texture_atlas.py", line 452, in has_texture

    return texture.name in self._atlas_regions
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

If anyone knows how to solve this, please help me.

here is my code:

```
# Colin A. Lewis
# Path of Torment
# Friday, April 1st  2022
# Coding, App & Game Design - A.M.


import os
import arcade

# Constants
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1900
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1200
SCREEN_TITLE = "Forest_of_Acid_&_Spikes"

# Constants used to scale our sprites from their original size
TILE_SCALING = 0.75
CHARACTER_SCALING = TILE_SCALING * 2
SPRITE_PIXEL_SIZE = 64
GRID_PIXEL_SIZE = SPRITE_PIXEL_SIZE * TILE_SCALING

# How many pixels to keep as a minimum margin between the character
# and the edge of the screen.
LEFT_VIEWPORT_MARGIN = 200
RIGHT_VIEWPORT_MARGIN = 200
BOTTOM_VIEWPORT_MARGIN = 150
TOP_VIEWPORT_MARGIN = 100

# Movement speed of player, in pixels per frame
PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED = 3
GRAVITY = 1.5
PLAYER_JUMP_SPEED = 30

PLAYER_START_X = 1
PLAYER_START_Y = 30

# Constants used to track if the player is facing left or right
RIGHT_FACING = 1
LEFT_FACING = 0

LAYER_NAME_TERRAIN = "Terrain"

LAYER_NAME_HAZARDS = "hazards"

LAYER_NAME_PLAYER = "player"


def load_frame(filename):
    return [
        arcade.load_texture(filename),
        arcade.load_texture(filename, flipped_horizontally=True),
    ]


class Entity(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.facing_direction = RIGHT_FACING
        self.currentTexture = 0

        self.scale = CHARACTER_SCALING
        character = f"./Character/Run (1).png"

        self.runFrames = []
        for i in range(1, 8):
            textures = f"{character}/Character/Run (1){i}.png"
            self.runFrames.append(textures)
            self.textures = self.runFrames[0][0]


class PlayerCharacter(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def updateAnimation(self, delta_time: float = 1 / 8):

        if self.change_x < 0 and self.facing_direction == RIGHT_FACING:
            self.facing_direction = LEFT_FACING

        elif self.change_x < 0 and self.facing_direction == LEFT_FACING:
            self.facing_direction = RIGHT_FACING

        # player run animation

        if self.change_x != 0:
            self.currentTexture += 1

            if self.currentTexture > len(self.runFrames) - 1:
                self.currentTexture = 0
            self.currentTexture = self.runFrames[self.currentTexture][self.facing_direction]


class MyGame(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        # Calls from the parent class and sets up the main window
        super().__init__(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)

        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.jump_needs_reset = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False

        # Set the path to start with this program
        # File assertion

        file_path = os.path.dirname(
            os.path.abspath("D:\Colin Lewis\pythonProject3\Lib"))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        # Our TileMap Object

        self.tile_map = ""

        # Our Scene Object
        self.scene = None

        # Separate variable that holds the player sprite
        self.player_sprite = None

        # Our 'physics' engine
        self.physics_engine = None

        # A Camera that can be used for scrolling the screen
        self.camera = None

        # A Camera that can be used to draw GUI elements
        self.gui_camera = None

        self.end_of_map = 0


    path = r"D:\\Colin Lewis\\pythonProject3\\Lib\\Forest_of_Acid_&_Spikes.tmx"
    assert os.path.isfile(path)
    with open(path, "r") as r:
        pass


    def setup(self):
        """Set up the game here. Call this function to restart the game."""

        # Setup the Cameras
        self.camera = arcade.Camera(self.width, self.height)
        self.gui_camera = arcade.Camera(self.width, self.height)

        # Map name
        map_name = "D:\\Colin Lewis\\pythonProject3\\Lib\\Forest_of_Acid_&_Spikes.tmx"

        # Layer Specific Options for the Tilemap
        layer_options = {
            LAYER_NAME_TERRAIN: {
                "use_spatial_hash": True,
            },
            LAYER_NAME_HAZARDS: {
                "use_spatial_hash": True,
            },
            LAYER_NAME_PLAYER: {
                "use_spacial_hash": True
            },
        }

        # Load in TileMap
        print("Loading Tile Map")
        print(map_name)

        self.tile_map = arcade.load_tilemap(map_name, TILE_SCALING, layer_options)
        print("Done loading Tile Map")

        self.scene = arcade.Scene.from_tilemap(self.tile_map)
        self.end_of_map = self.tile_map.width * GRID_PIXEL_SIZE

        self.player_sprite = PlayerCharacter()

        self.player_sprite.center_x = (
                self.tile_map.tile_width * TILE_SCALING * PLAYER_START_X)

        self.player_sprite.center_y = (
                self.tile_map.tile_height * TILE_SCALING * PLAYER_START_Y
        )

        self.scene.add_sprite(LAYER_NAME_PLAYER, self.player_sprite)

        self.end_of_map = self.tile_map.width * GRID_PIXEL_SIZE


        # Create the 'physics engine'
        self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEnginePlatformer(
            self.player_sprite,
            gravity_constant=GRAVITY,
            walls=(self.scene[LAYER_NAME_TERRAIN]))

    def on_draw(self):
        """Render the screen."""
        # Clear the screen to the background color
        self.clear()

        # Activate the game camera
        self.camera.use()

        # Draw our Scene
        self.scene.draw()

        # Activate the GUI camera before drawing GUI elements
        self.gui_camera.use()

    def process_keychange(self):

        # Process left/right
        if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = -PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED
        else:
            self.player_sprite.change_x = 0



    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):

        if key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.left_pressed = True
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.right_pressed = True
        self.process_keychange()

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):

        if key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.left_pressed = False
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.right_pressed = False
        self.process_keychange()



    def center_camera_to_player(self, speed=0.2):
        screen_center_x = self.player_sprite.center_x - (self.camera.viewport_width / 2)
        screen_center_y = self.player_sprite.center_y - (
                self.camera.viewport_height / 2
        )
        if screen_center_x < 0:
            screen_center_x = 0
        if screen_center_y < 0:
            screen_center_y = 0

        player_centered = screen_center_x, screen_center_y
        self.camera.move_to(player_centered, speed)

        # Draw hit boxes.
        for wall in self.wall_list:
            wall.draw_hit_box(arcade.color.BLACK, 3)

            self.player_sprite.draw_hit_box(arcade.color.RED, 3)


def main():
    """Main function"""
    window = MyGame()
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is where I think the error is coming from in the code:

```
print("Loading Tile Map")
        print(map_name)

        self.tile_map = arcade.load_tilemap(map_name, TILE_SCALING, layer_options)
        print("Done loading Tile Map")

        self.scene = arcade.Scene.from_tilemap(self.tile_map)
        self.end_of_map = self.tile_map.width * GRID_PIXEL_SIZE

        self.player_sprite = PlayerCharacter()

        self.player_sprite.center_x = (
                self.tile_map.tile_width * TILE_SCALING * PLAYER_START_X)

        self.player_sprite.center_y = (
                self.tile_map.tile_height * TILE_SCALING * PLAYER_START_Y
        )

        self.scene.add_sprite(LAYER_NAME_PLAYER, self.player_sprite)

        self.end_of_map = self.tile_map.width * GRID_PIXEL_SIZE


        # Create the 'physics engine'
        self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEnginePlatformer(
            self.player_sprite,
            gravity_constant=GRAVITY,
            walls=(self.scene[LAYER_NAME_TERRAIN]))

    def on_draw(self):
        """Render the screen."""
        # Clear the screen to the background color
        self.clear()

        # Activate the game camera
        self.camera.use()

        # Draw our Scene
        self.scene.draw()

        # Activate the GUI camera before drawing GUI elements
        self.gui_camera.use()
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code to the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The texture assigned on your player sprites seesm to be a string. That is not correct.